# Insert an image with ruby in popover bootstrap

Tags: ruby, image, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Here is the image ruby code  I try to put in popover

```
 <div class="idea">
 <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-lg popover-img" data-content="<%= cl_image_tag(@hiragana.upload, :width => 260, :height => 340) %>"></i>
 </div>
```

Here is the js popover code

```
  <script >
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".popover-img").popover({
          html: true,
          trigger: "hover",
          content: "",
          placement:'bottom'
        });
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML?

Comment: Either you are showing us what is written in your erb file, or you are not using erb files and you should be.

Comment: @JustinWood Yes it is erb.html file here the code I use only js and erb.html files, because I xant to generate a different picture on each show view i create.

Comment: We want to see the HTML that gets generated by the erb file.

Comment: @JustinWood  I dont understand here is the code Html.erb that appears on my Show View You want to see the New Form View? Html is mixed in my ruby code.

Comment: @JustinWood I use Boootstrap for the popover and the image I upload I used is CarrierWave. I don't want to use `<img src="picture.png">` in the data content but call cloudinary `<% cl_image_tag @hiragana.upload %>` (Upload is image and Hiragana is object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div type="button" class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-lg popover-img" data-toggle="popover" title="" data-content=<%=cl_image_tag(@hiragana.upload, :width => 260, :height => 340)%> > contenu de ce que je dois cliquer dessu pour afficher le popover</div>`

Comment: `data-content=<%="#{cl_image_tag(@hiragana.upload, :width => 260, :height => 340)}"%>`